# iOS push data to Parse in the 2nd row, not at the top

Tags: ios, cloud, parse-platform

When I upload any data onto the Parse cloud, it stores the row at the top of the table. So every time a new row is added it gets stored at the top.

However, when I retrieve all the rows, the data is retrieved bottom up approach.

So let's say initially cloud is empty.

```
Push a
Cloud Looks like :  a

Push b
Cloud Looks like :  b  a

Push c
Cloud Looks like :  c  b  a

And now when I retrieve the data, i get it like:  a  b  c
```

Now what I want is when data is inserted it is put at the 2nd location and not the first location.

Example:

```
Initial Cloud :  "X"

Push a:  "X"  a
Push b:  "X"  b  a
Push c:  "X"  c  b  a
```

Is there any way I can push data in Parse like this?

I'm doing because when I retrieve data, I wish to execute a method after all the data is retrieved in the background thread. So this way when I reach at X, I can call my method.

Found a solution to the problem....different approach though:

1. I count the number of objects for that query
2. Keep a counter increasing every time a record is fetched
3. when counter reached = total number of objects  , then execute method.

   ```
   NSInteger count= [query countObjects];
   for (PFObject *obj in objects) {
   [Names addObject:LastName];
   if ([Names count] == count) {
             [self getResults];
            }  }
   ```

^^^ solution is wrong

This way apparently does block the main thread, so there's a possibility of the app being killed.

Does anyone have any other solutions?

Answer (score 1):

The data stored in the Parse Cloud is in an arbitrary order.  Due to the way they currently store the data you may see new data at the end but this behaviour should not be relied upon.

If you want to retrieve data in a specific order then you should add a [sorting operation](https://parse.com/docs/osx/api/Classes/PFQuery.html#task_Sorting) to your `PFQuery` rather than trying to store the data in a specific order.

I am not sure what you are trying to achieve with your second code block. What does `[self getResults]` do?

If you want to execute some code after the results have been retrieved, why not just use [`findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock`](https://parse.com/docs/osx/api/Classes/PFQuery.html#//api/name/findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock%3a)?

This allows you to specify code to be executed once the data is received -

```
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
     if (!error) {
         // The find succeeded.
         names = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:objects];

         // Do something with the found objects
         for (PFObject *object in objects) {                
             NSLog(@"Object Name: %@", object.objectId);
         }


    } else {
         // Log details of the failure
         NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
     }
 }];
```

If you need to update any UI from the block (or a method called within the block) then you should perform that on the main thread -

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self updateMyUIWithResult:objects];
    });
```

So, putting it together you get  -

```
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
     if (!error) {
         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self updateMyUIWithResult:objects];
    });


    } else {
         // Log details of the failure
         NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
     }
 }];
```

Comment: If I use findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock, how do I wait for the data to retrieve completely then perform some method? Right now I have 2 buttons. I retrieve data with one button, wait for a couple of seconds then use the second button to perform a method. However, I don't wish to use 2 buttons. So as soon as the data is completely retrieved the method should be performed. 

also, the solution I posted is wrong. It DOES block the main thread, so a bad internet connection might kill the map.

Comment: I updated my answer to show how to use a block and update your UI on the main thread